# how to find correct path in shell script using array

Tags: linux, shell

Hi I need help to create shell script.

let suppose I have below 3 folder location in server but out of 3. 1 or 2 location is correct rest are wrong. I Need to write a shell script to check all 3 folder location. If location is correct then execute rest of code otherwise break the condition.

```
array = ("/data/jenkins" "/home/jenkins" "/jenkins")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you have to do:

```
    #! /bin/bash

server_name=$(hostname)


arr=("data/jenkins" "home/jenkins" "jenkins")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   :
   ls -A $i 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
   echo "Folder exists on ${server_name}" 
else 
echo 'Folder does not exist'
fi
done
```

1. You loop through your array of directories.
2. You list each individual directory via `ls -A $i 2>/dev/null`

- **-A** -in case the directories are hidden.
- **2>/dev/null** - basically makes the ls command non-verbose, otherwise you'll be getting error messages for the non-existing folders.

From there on you need to check whether the output of the ls command was succesfull or not.

In order to achieve this you can use '**$?**' which is used to find the return value of the last executed command, then you compare the value to '0' (the "success" case for this command).

If the value is 0 - Bingo, your folder exists, if it's some other number, the folder doesn't exist.

Save the file on one of your servers and from here on you have to connect to your other servers and execute this script.

You can do this by first creating a file called "servers.txt", adding the IPs of the servers inside of it.

Then executing this line of code:

```
for server in $(cat servers.txt) ; do ssh USERNAME@${server} 'bash -s' < ./name_of_script.sh ; done
```

directly inside the terminal of the server where you've saved the script above should prompt you to input the password for the specific user and then should execute the script on all of your servers.

Comment: Hi Its working for only 1st location. not checking rest 2 of the location

Comment: Are all three of those directories in one parent directory?

i.e

```root
/data/jenkins
/jenkins
/home/jenkins``` ?

I have created two of the directories on my test env (data/jenkins + jenkins), both of those are placed in a root directory and when running the script this is the result I get.

[link](https://prnt.sc/pBrxrBpLqiCv)

Comment: out of 3 only 1 directory is available on one server. I have 3 server with 3 different directory and i want to use same script in all server

Comment: In this case, you'll have to further expand this.

Create a file named "servers.txt" and put the IPs of the servers inside.

From there on you'll need to somehow connect via SSH to all of your servers, you can do it in this way ->

```for server in $(cat servers.txt) ; do ssh USERNAME@${server} 'bash -s' < ./name_of_script.sh ; done```

You need to run this command on the server where the script in my initial answer is located.

You'll be then prompted to enter the password of the user that you're trying to access, and once you've done that you should get the results which you want.